# emacs follow-mode use/alternatives

Tags: emacs

I have recently started using Emacs `follow-mode` to see more of documents I am working on.  Unfortunately, it seems to have some limitations, at least as I am using it.  I very often use <kbd>C-x b</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> to toggle between two buffers, but this doesn't work as I would expect with `follow-mode`.  I would expect that if both buffers are set up to use `follow-mode`, it should switch both windows, but it does not.  Also, even if only one buffer is set to use `follow-mode`, hitting <kbd>C-x b</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> after switching to that buffer should get me back to my original configuration, but instead it switches the active window to some third buffer.  Can anyone explain some better `follow-mode` idioms or else an alternative to `follow-mode`?